# Flutter DropdownButton in DataTable

Tags: flutter, dart, datatable, dropdownbutton

In flutter I'm trying to have one of the columns of a DataTable be a DropdownButton, where the user can select from the DropdownButton and it changes that cells value (and not any other cells, so don't change values in the 1st column at all).

See below for example code (DropdownButton doesn't change cell value), also in [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/8e908a9180b439c857c496811a5f0e3a).

[image]

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: DataTableDemo(),
    );
  }
}

class User {
  String firstName;
  String lastName;

  User({this.firstName, this.lastName});

  static List<User> getUsers() {
    return <User>[
      User(firstName: "Paul", lastName: "Rudd"),
      User(firstName: "Owen", lastName: "Wilson"),
      User(firstName: "Jonah", lastName: "Hill"),
    ];
  }
}

class DataTableDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  DataTableDemo() : super();

  final String title = "Data Table Flutter Demo";

  @override
  DataTableDemoState createState() => DataTableDemoState();
}

class DataTableDemoState extends State<DataTableDemo> {
  List<User> users;
  

  @override
  void initState() {
    users = User.getUsers();
    super.initState();
  }

  List<String> lastNamesList = <String>[
    'Rudd',
    'Wilson',
    'Hill',
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('DropdownButton in DataTable'),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          child: DataTable(
            columns: [
              DataColumn(
                label: Text("FIRST NAME"),
                numeric: false,
                tooltip: "This is First Name",
              ),
              DataColumn(
                label: Text("LAST NAME"),
                numeric: false,
                tooltip: "This is Last Name",
              ),
            ],
            rows: users
                .map(
                  (user) => DataRow(cells: [
                    DataCell(
                      Text(user.firstName),
                      onTap: () {
                        print('Selected firstName: ${user.firstName}');
                      },
                    ),

                    DataCell(DropdownButton<String>(
                      value: user.lastName,
                      onChanged: (String newValue) {
                        setState(() {
                          //help! 
                        });
                      },
                      items: lastNamesList
                          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                          value: value,
                          child: Text(value),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                    ))
                  ]),
                )
                .toList(),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Step 1: You can use a `List` `selectedUser` to record each selection 
Step 2: Use `selectedUser.asMap().entries.map` to get `index` 
code snippet

```
List<User> selectedUser;
...
rows: selectedUser.asMap().entries.map((user) {
              int idx = user.key;
              print(idx);
              return DataRow(cells: [
                DataCell(
                  Text(selectedUser[idx].firstName),
                  onTap: () {
                    print('Selected firstName: ${selectedUser[idx].firstName}');
                  },
                ),
                DataCell(DropdownButton<User>(
                  value: selectedUser[idx],
                  onChanged: (User newUser) {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedUser[idx] = newUser;
                    });
                  },
                  items: users.map<DropdownMenuItem<User>>((User value) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem<User>(
                      value: value,
                      child: Text(value.lastName),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                ))
              ]);
            }).toList(),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: DataTableDemo(),
    );
  }
}

class User {
  String firstName;
  String lastName;

  User({this.firstName, this.lastName});

  static List<User> getUsers() {
    return <User>[
      User(firstName: "Paul", lastName: "Rudd"),
      User(firstName: "Owen", lastName: "Wilson"),
      User(firstName: "Jonah", lastName: "Hill"),
    ];
  }
}

class DataTableDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  DataTableDemo() : super();

  final String title = "Data Table Flutter Demo";

  @override
  DataTableDemoState createState() => DataTableDemoState();
}

class DataTableDemoState extends State<DataTableDemo> {
  List<User> users;
  List<User> selectedUser;

  @override
  void initState() {
    users = User.getUsers();
    selectedUser = List.from(users);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('DropdownButton in DataTable'),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          child: DataTable(
            columns: [
              DataColumn(
                label: Text("FIRST NAME"),
                numeric: false,
                tooltip: "This is First Name",
              ),
              DataColumn(
                label: Text("LAST NAME"),
                numeric: false,
                tooltip: "This is Last Name",
              ),
            ],
            rows: selectedUser.asMap().entries.map((user) {
              int idx = user.key;
              print(idx);
              return DataRow(cells: [
                DataCell(
                  Text(selectedUser[idx].firstName),
                  onTap: () {
                    print('Selected firstName: ${selectedUser[idx].firstName}');
                  },
                ),
                DataCell(DropdownButton<User>(
                  value: selectedUser[idx],
                  onChanged: (User newUser) {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedUser[idx] = newUser;
                    });
                  },
                  items: users.map<DropdownMenuItem<User>>((User value) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem<User>(
                      value: value,
                      child: Text(value.lastName),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                ))
              ]);
            }).toList(),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

full code 2, first column value not change

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: DataTableDemo(),
    );
  }
}

class User {
  String firstName;
  String lastName;

  User({this.firstName, this.lastName});

  static List<User> getUsers() {
    return <User>[
      User(firstName: "Paul", lastName: "Rudd"),
      User(firstName: "Owen", lastName: "Wilson"),
      User(firstName: "Jonah", lastName: "Hill"),
    ];
  }
}

class DataTableDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  DataTableDemo() : super();

  final String title = "Data Table Flutter Demo";

  @override
  DataTableDemoState createState() => DataTableDemoState();
}

class DataTableDemoState extends State<DataTableDemo> {
  List<User> users;
  List<User> selectedUser;

  @override
  void initState() {
    users = User.getUsers();
    selectedUser = List.from(users);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('DropdownButton in DataTable'),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          child: DataTable(
            columns: [
              DataColumn(
                label: Text("FIRST NAME"),
                numeric: false,
                tooltip: "This is First Name",
              ),
              DataColumn(
                label: Text("LAST NAME"),
                numeric: false,
                tooltip: "This is Last Name",
              ),
            ],
            rows: users.asMap().entries.map((user) {
              int idx = user.key;
              print(idx);
              return DataRow(cells: [
                /*DataCell(
                  Text(selectedUser[idx].firstName),
                  onTap: () {
                    print('Selected firstName: ${selectedUser[idx].firstName}');
                  },
                ),*/
                DataCell(
                  Text(user.value.firstName),
                  onTap: () {
                    print('Selected firstName: ${user.value.firstName}');
                  },
                ),
                DataCell(DropdownButton<User>(
                  value: selectedUser[idx],
                  onChanged: (User newUser) {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedUser[idx] = newUser;
                    });
                  },
                  items: users.map<DropdownMenuItem<User>>((User value) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem<User>(
                      value: value,
                      child: Text(value.lastName),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                ))
              ]);
            }).toList(),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey I'm trying to leave the firstName's as is, not change them. Do you know how to just make the 2nd column change? I want to be able to set the initial values with getUsers, then be able to change the 2nd column to the names in the list lastNamesList.

Comment: Thanks, I think I asked the question in the wrong way. It looks like you have deleted the lastNamesList and populated the DropdownButton options from the User values. I want the DropdownButton options to come from a list as there may be options which isn't populated already from getUsers. I have posted another question which will hopefully be less confusing! Sorry!  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64327653/flutter-dropdownbutton-in-datatable-dropdownbutton-values-from-list] @chunhunghan